# Consulta MySQL três tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta no banco de dados MYSQL, mas a consulta não está voltando o que eu queria. Quero fazer uma consulta onde retorne todos os módulos e os módulos que a empresa tem com a cláusula `where` em `Empresa_ID`.

Tentativa do MySQL:

```
   SELECT empresas.empresa_id
         ,empresas.empresa_razaosocial
         ,modulos.modulo_id
         ,modulos.modulo_nome
         ,empresa_modulo.modulo_id
     FROM empresa_modulo
    RIGHT JOIN modulos
       ON modulos.modulo_id = empresa_modulo.modulo_id
    RIGHT JOIN empresas
       ON empresas.empresa_id = empresa_modulo.empresa_id
   UNION
   SELECT empresas.empresa_id
         ,empresas.empresa_razaosocial
         ,modulos.modulo_id
         ,modulos.modulo_nome
         ,empresa_modulo.modulo_id
     FROM empresa_modulo
    RIGHT JOIN modulos
       ON modulos.modulo_id = empresa_modulo.modulo_id
    RIGHT JOIN empresas
       ON empresa_modulo.empresa_id = empresas.empresa_id
    WHERE empresas.empresa_id = 1;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz essa consulta, mas não tive sucesso. Como posso realizar esta consulta?

Uma consulta que retorne todos os modulos e os modulos que a empresa tem.

Comment: Sem ter um exemplo dos dados fica difícil ajudar. Aparentemente sua consulta está certa, não pode ser dados que não foram encontrados nos `right join`?

Comment: O que você quer? O que retorna? Explique melhor.

Comment: Está ae, corrigir

Comment: @JoanMarcos Você precisa mostrar uma amostra dos dados, o que você está recebendo no momento, e o que você gostaria de receber quando estiver certo.

Comment: @user94991 está ae o resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joan, o print do resultado é o que vc espera, certo?

A sua consulta esta errada, uma vez que você está querendo todos os modulo não há a necessidade de você usar `right join`.

```
--Nesse select você vai relacionar todos os modulo que tem relacionamento.
SELECT e.empresa_id
      ,e.empresa_razaosocial
      ,m.modulo_id
      ,m.modulo_nome
      ,em.modulo_id
  FROM empresa_modulo em
  JOIN modulos m
    ON m.modulo_id = em.modulo_id
  JOIN empresas e
    ON e.empresa_id = em.empresa_id
---Se adicionar o where, você selecionará apenas a empresa com o id 1.
 WHERE e.empresa_id = 1;
```

Você sabe a diferença de `Union` e `Union ALL`?

Quando você usar o `UNION` ele retornará apenas os registros unicos, com o `ALL` você terá linha repetidas.

Tente usar o seguinte:

```
SELECT e.empresa_id
      ,e.empresa_razaosocial
      ,m.modulo_id
      ,m.modulo_nome
      ,em.modulo_id
  FROM empresa_modulo em
 CROSS JOIN modulos m
    ON m.modulo_id = em.modulo_id
 CROSS JOIN empresas e
    ON e.empresa_id = em.empresa_id;
```